# Can't caching object in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, memcached

I have this following code in the *Address* controller

```
public function index()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('isLogin')) {
            $this->load->driver('cache');
            $this->load->model('MemberModel');
            if(!$this->cache->get('province') == false) {
                $this->load->model('ShippingModel');
                $data['provinces'] = $this->ShippingModel->the_provinces(); // it will return json object
                $this->cache->save('province', $data['provinces'], 300);
            } else {
                $data['provinces'] = $this->cache->get('province');
            }
            $userdata = $this->MemberModel->getProfile($this->session->userdata('userid'));
            $data['user'] = $userdata;

            $this->display_member_area('member/address', $data);
        }
        else {
            redirect(base_url());
        }
    }
```

When I want to get the data using:

```
var_dump($this->cache->get('province'));
```

the result I get always shows

```
bool(false)
```

but when I tried to do this instead

```
var_dump($data['provinces']) // it's show me json object, that I want
```

Can anyone please show me where I'am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your CI version?

Comment: where did you set the cache used here? `$this->cache->get('province')` returning false when cache module used cannot find the cache key.

Comment: @AbdulAhmadMatin I use version 3.1.5

Comment: @Charis I  set on on there `$this->cache->save('province', $data['provinces'], 300);` at line 9 on my code above.

Comment: Can you ensure that you cache driver work as intended? Maybe using simple string data to save and retrieve it. Once before my team see something similar and it turns out one person tried to save some non serialized resource object.

Comment: @Charis I was tried using simple string like "test". and it still not work. do you have another idea to fix this Charis? Thanks

Comment: Then your driver is not working. What cache engine did you setup on your environment? memcached? Have you set the correct configuration on your config?

Comment: @Charis I didn't set anything in config. Am I need set up something in Config? because there is no instruction to set something in config when I read the CI documentation. Can you please show me what config that I need to set up Charis. Thanks in advance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174566/discussion-between-charis-and-bagongpct).

Comment: I submit a possible answer for your problem. Check bellow.

Comment: @Charis. I'am Sorry for long time reply. I was busy with another task. and actually I was skiped this error. I use another simply alternative. Thank you very much for your help. GBU. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove `false` from the `if` condition and use this code.

```
       if(!$this->cache->get('province')) {
            $this->load->model('ShippingModel');
            $data['provinces'] = $this->ShippingModel->the_provinces();
            $this->cache->save('province', $data['provinces'], 300);
        } else {
            $data['provinces'] = $this->cache->get('province');
        }
```

Comment: edit your code like this  `$provinces = $this->ShippingModel->the_provinces();` 
 `$this->cache->save('province', $provinces, 300);`

Comment: no error appear. but when I do `var_dump($this->cache->get('province')); ` it always return _bool(false)_. and I was tried your code above this comment. but still return FALSE. thanks AbdulAhmadMatin

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct credential on your config at:

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/memcached.php

it will be at you `application/config/memcached.php` file. Hostname is the ip you setup your memcached instance. You could provide multiple server if you wish.

[reference on installing memcached](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-memcached-on-ubuntu-16-04)